# Fullcalendar eventLimit not using popover

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar with eventLimit.

I don't want to use the popover function of eventLimit, I would like just to show the remaining events in the same view.

I'm using the basicWeek but if I set:

```
elementClick: 'basicWeek'
```

Clicking on the more link does not work at all.

Please see the example at the following [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/pwyw2sfy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
eventLimitClick: "basicWeek"
```

not "elementClick".

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimitClick/

There's no "elementClick" option in the documentation, as far as I can see.

EDIT:

In your JSFiddle I can see you have used "eventLimitClick" correctly. However, you're asking it to go to the same view ("basicWeek") that you're already in, which will essentially do nothing.

Did you mean to make it go to, say, the "basicDay" view to get more detail? If so, then in order to make it work, you then need to override the "eventLimit" for the day view in question, so that you don't simply end up with the "show more" type link on that view instead of the actual events. To do that, you need to update the fullCalendar and momentJS versions you're using in the Fiddle, so that fullCalendar supports view-specific options (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/).

In short, what you'd need to do is set the options like this:

```
eventLimit: 1,
eventLimitClick: 'basicDay', //go to a DAY view, not the same week view
views: { 
  basicDay: { eventLimit: false } //for the day view, remove the event limit
},
```

See a working fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pwyw2sfy/3/

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to show the other result in the same view. I would like to have show more just open the rest of the events on the same view.

Comment: It doesn't work like that, sorry. Anyway if you want to do that, why bother with "eventLimit" at all? It's designed for a situation where there isn't enough space to show all the events. If you've got enough space for it to expand and show all the events, then you don't need it in the first place.

Comment: Well thanks for the explaination. But for usability purpose it can be useful. I want the user to show the list of events only when interested and not to see 20/30 events per day....Anyway I doubt that there is no solution for what I need...Thanks anyway

Comment: From what I know of usability studies, making the user click an extra time to see what they could have been shown already actually _decreases_ usability, because it hides information that was otherwise available. I take the point about not flooding the user with 20/30 events. But if you're concerned about that, maybe it would be best to start in, say, month view, with a limit of 5 or 6, and then have it switch to an agenda view if they want details of a specific day or week?